# MVC Dropdown List containing Method Actions for Models, Possible?

Tags: razor, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have several models in my application which I want to create functionality to allow users to edit/create values within the database.

Of course each controller contains the action method, but I want to be able to provide the user with a dropdown that lists all of the models so when they select an option from the dropdown it takes the user to the correct view to Edit or Ceate an item in that model.

I.e.  I have models for GoverningBody, Directorate, Region, and OperationalTeam, each of them have the following elements;

.....Id (int),
.....Name (string),
Live (bit)

(Live is used as a method for soft deleting of the value in order to protect historic data) I want to have a dropdown with these listed, the user selects one from the dropdown, clicks a button, and the user is then provided the Edit view, or Create view for that selected model.

I've done a but of research on the internet but cannot find any kind of solution nor anything that explains if what I'm attempting to achieve is even possible, and its most likely down to the fact that I don't know enough to know what I should be looking for.

I'm not asking for anyone to provide me with a solution, but any advice on what/where I should be looking, what terms to look for and learn about so I can attempt something on my own.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You can create two `DropdownList`, One is choose model and the other is choose action, I create a simple demo to show my opinion, Hope it can help you.

First, I create two models for this demo (`User`, `GoverningBody`), Then I Use Model Name to create controller with CURD action

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Update()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Delete()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

public class GoverningBodyController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Update()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Delete()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**HomeController**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> model = new List<SelectListItem>();
            model.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "User", Value = "User" });
            model.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "GoverningBody", Value = "GoverningBody" });

            ViewBag.model = model;

            List<SelectListItem> action = new List<SelectListItem>();
            action.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Create", Value = "Create" });
            action.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Edit", Value = "Edit" });
            action.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Update", Value = "Update" });
            action.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Delete", Value = "Delete" });

            ViewBag.action = action;

            return View();
        }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Choose a model and an action you want to do with this model</h2>

<div>
    Model: <select asp-items="@ViewBag.model" name="model" id="model"></select>
            Action : <select asp-items="@ViewBag.action" name="action" id="action"></select>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick=go()>Go~</button>


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function go(){
            
            var controller = document.getElementById("model").value;
            var action = document.getElementById("action").value;
            window.location.href= "/"+controller+"/"+action;
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Demo**:[image]